# Compare SSL certificates via signature: is it enough?

Tags: java, android, ssl-certificate

The system architecture that I'm working on requires the comparison between two SSL/TLS (typically X.509) certificates. That is to say, I need to verify if two certificates are the the same or not.

I don't care if they're expired or self-signed, I just want to be sure that they have not being altered in any way.

Which is the most correct way to perform such operation? Would it be enough to compare the two signatures (two byte[]) of those certificates or is this operation prone to exploits I haven't considered so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think comparing the two signatures is sufficient, unless your code directly gets the certificates from some instance which assures that the signature has also been *checked* against the certificate itself. So under many circumstances, I'd say: *no*.

I believe the most flexible, correct way would be to check the integrity of the two certificates (body vs signature) individually and then directly compare all the information in the certificates which you require to be identical. (I'm putting it this way because I'm not sure you require *total* identity).

However, if your goal is really to check the certificate a server sends for authenticity, then it's not necessarily wise to have a copy of the whole certificate in your code; in this case, you could verify the server's certificate and then check its body against a secure hash which is stored in your app.

Comment: I need to verify the _total_ identity. As far as I've understood from your answer, you're suggesting to 
1) verify the certificate's signature against itself 
2) verify that the two signatures match

Is it the case? By the way, my application is not storing any certificate, all is done at run-time.

Comment: @dextor I would _not_ compare the two _signatures_ after validating the certificates against their signatures, but rather compare the _certificates_ or their relevant parts against each other after validationg the certificates against their signatures.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is certainly doable by doing a raw-comparison field-by-field. What is still not clear to me is why do you think that a "whole certificate" comparison (let's say by hashing their encoded form and comparing the results one against the other) is not safe enough.

Comment: @dextor I did not intend to express suc a concern. One can definitely compare hashes of the two certificates. However, those would have to be computed, and that should take longer than comparing the certificates directly. If you ask yourself why I wouldn't compare signatures (which are hashes) once I know they match the certificates, it's more because you said you'd potentially handle different certificate types, so maybe even signatures which today are considered weak, so I wouldn't rely on that just because I don't have to. :)